# what ever i type it replys command not found in terminal :export:13: not valid in this context:

Tags: terminal

/Users/username/.bash_profile:12: no such file or directory: /opt/home
/Users/username/.bash_profile:export:13: not valid in this context: brew/bin:/Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/usernameLibrary/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
username@R7CKGHYCX1 ~ % open ~/.bash_profile
zsh: command not found: open
username@R7CKGHYCX1 ~ % java --version
zsh: command not found: java
username@R7CKGHYCX1 ~ %
i have tried to reset the terminal. But it doesnt work me.

i tried this also,

On MacOS BigSur Click Terminal >> Preferences change the from /bin/zsh to /bin/bash Close and reopen the terminal

I have installed, and I have used it before on my computer. I am trying to get it to work now, but when I type in terminal (mac os), it returns "command not found". I have navigate into username and it is still not working. Am i missing something? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
eval $(/opt/home brew/bin/brew shellenv)
export PATH=/opt/home brew/bin:$PATH
```

I have edited this line in `.bash_profile` from your user Location type <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
It shows `.bash_profile` click then edit that two lines.